# How to use subroutines in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code...

```
<script>
    if (document.getElementById("hidden").checked === true && document.getElementById("unlisted").checked === false) {
        const currentBaseValue1 = $('#selectedBaseRelease').val();
        const currentBaseValue = currentBaseValue1+'.hidden';
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#baseText').empty().append(currentBaseValue);
            $('#selectedBaseRelease').on('click.select2', function(event) {
                const currentBaseValue = $('#selectedBaseRelease').val();
                $('#baseText').empty().load(currentBaseValue);
            });
            $('#baseText').empty().load(currentBaseValue);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Throughout the rest of the code, the leading if statement varies, as do the const declarations. But the $(document).ready(function() {...} section is reused over and over again, unchanged, so I would like to represent it as a function/subroutine. At this point the total code is over 400 lines, but could reduce to less than 200 lines if I could get this function/subroutine to work. I have tried doing this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadbaseText() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#baseText').empty().append(currentBaseValue);
            $('#selectedBaseRelease').on('click.select2', function(event) {
                const currentBaseValue = $('#selectedBaseRelease').val();
                $('#baseText').empty().load(currentBaseValue);
            });
            $('#baseText').empty().load(currentBaseValue);
        });
    }
</script>
```

...followed, eventually, by...

```
<script>
    if (document.getElementById("hidden").checked === true && document.getElementById("unlisted").checked === false) {
        const currentBaseValue1 = $('#selectedBaseRelease').val();
        const currentBaseValue = currentBaseValue1+'.hidden';
        loadbaseText();
    }
</script>
```

...but it is not working. I am an HTML/Javascript rookie, so I am sure this not a complicated problem, but I cannot seem to find the right solution. Can someone help? My best guess at the moment is that the scope of the const is inadequate in some way.

Thanks!

Comment: Is that function definitely being called? console.log is your friend

Comment: Try passing `currentBaseValue1` and `currentBaseValue` to your `loadBaseText()` function as arguments.

Comment: loadBasetext sets an event handler and then exits - calling loadBasetext does not execute the code defined in the handler - that happens once, when the page finishes loading.  What I think you want to do is define a function outside of document.ready, call that function from within document.ready, and also call that same function elsewhere

Comment: @James, while you're not wrong that it is not necessary to include this all over the place, the callback will nevertheless be invoked immediately if the condition is currently met.

Comment: @OliverRadini, that's not correct. `.ready()` will invoke its callback immediately if the DOM is already loaded. [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: @"Fissure King", yes,adding the const declarations as arguments was all I needed--loadbaseText(currentBaseValue) works! (I also referenced the const in the function definition, e.g. function loadbaseText(currentBaseValue) {...} Thank you!

Comment: @fissure-king thanks for letting me know! I've now deleted my comment

Answer (score 2):

Just use the value as parameter like this

```
function loadbaseText(value) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#baseText').empty().append(value);
            $('#selectedBaseRelease').on('click.select2', function(event) {
                const currentBaseValue = $('#selectedBaseRelease').val();
                $('#baseText').empty().load(value);
            });
            $('#baseText').empty().load(value);
        });
    }
```

And use it like this:

```
if (document.getElementById("hidden").checked === true && document.getElementById("unlisted").checked === false) {
        const currentBaseValue1 = $('#selectedBaseRelease').val();
        const currentBaseValue = currentBaseValue1+'.hidden';
        loadbaseText(currentBaseValue);
    }
```